# mon installation in Linux/Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Hi I am installing mon in Debian/Linux using command `apt-get install mon`

But it's showing the error and aborting the installation.
Error is

```
apt-get install mon

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mon
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/179kB of archives.
After this operation, 741kB of additional disk space will be used.

(Reading database ... 106004 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mon (from .../mon_0.99.2-13_i386.deb) ...
Looking for user name availability (mon)... already taken.

Installation aborted!


dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mon_0.99.2-13_i386.deb (--unpack):
subprocess pre-installation script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/mon_0.99.2-13_i386.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Sounds like that mon deb package was not transferred completely or it was otherwise corrupted. What if you perform rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/mon_0.99.2-13_i386.deb and then retry the installation?

Comment: You're only showing the aftermath of the error. Edit your question to include the whole output from the `apt-get install` command.

Answer (score 3):

> Looking for user name availability (mon)... already taken.

The `mon` program runs as a dedicated system user also called `mon`. The installer tried to create this system user, but there is already a user with this name on your system.

If you can remove or rename the existing `mon` user (and group if you also have one), this will let you install the `mon` package. Otherwise you'll have to pick a different name to run the `mon` program under, which requires modifying and recompiling the source package.

---

EDIT: Here's how to rename the existing `mon` user to `newname` (pick a better name), at least the easy part. I assume this is a local user, not a NIS or LDAP user (otherwise the resolution would be very different). It's ok if some of the `mv` commands are for files that don't exist, just skip them.

```
usermod -l newname mon
groupmod -n newname mon
mv /var/spool/cron/crontabs/mon /var/spool/cron/crontabs/newname
mv /var/spool/main/mon /var/spool/main/newname
```

The hard part is finding any reference you have on your system to the old `mon` user name. There's no hard-and-fast rule for this, it depends a lot on what that user's been doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have no idea how to rename existing mon user.Please explain in detail how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you give me the urls to know more about mon because I have to write the startup script for mon(/etc/init.d/mon)

Comment: @sjain: there is already a startup script for `mon` in the Debian package. In what way does it not suit you?

Comment: Actually I had to prepare a document so that others can install this in the fresh machine.I had the machine with already installed mon.So to check the steps I deleted the mon dorectories and the startup scripts too.That's why it is not in my machine. If it comes with debian package then no problem I will get it from the other machine. 
Thanks a lot for your replies.